# Como converter uma view em MySQL para PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma migração de um banco de dados MySQL para PostgreSQL, porém a minha view não está sendo aceita, já rodei toda internet procurando uma maneira de modificá-la más nenhuma funcionou, alguém sabe como poderia ser feito, ou um tutorial aonde eu possa aprender?

```
CREATE VIEW anuncio_points
AS
SELECT
a.*,
(if(p.points is null, 0, sum(p.points)) + u.points) as points
FROM anuncios as a
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN points as p ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

A propósito, o problema é no if:

```
ERROR:  function if(boolean, integer, numeric) does not exist
LINE 5: (if(p.points is null, 0, sum(p.points)) + u.points) as point...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

```
CREATE VIEW anuncio_points
AS
    SELECT
    a.*,
    (CASE WHEN p.points is null THEN 0 ELSE sum(p.points) END) + u.points as points
    FROM anuncios as a
    LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
    LEFT JOIN points as p ON p.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY a.id;
```

ou, de maneira mais simples:

```
CREATE VIEW anuncio_points
AS
    SELECT
    a.*,
    (sum(COALESCE(p.points, 0) + u.points) as points
    FROM anuncios as a
    LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
    LEFT JOIN points as p ON p.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY a.id;
```